# Using """ and escape sequences in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python right now and wanted to try all the escape sequences but my code seems to have a bug. Please help me find it?

My Code:

```
string = """backslash - \\\nsingle quote - \'\ndouble quote - \"
ASCII bell - \a Lorem
ASCII backspace - \b Lorem
ACII formfeed - \f Lorem
Unicode - \N{prabhu} Ipsum
Carriage return - \r Ipsum
16 bit Hex value - \u1234
32 bit Hex value - \U12345678 ASCII Vertical tab - \v
Octal value character - \123
Hex value - \x12 
"""

print(string)
```

--> Error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 137-146: unknown unicode character name

Comment: Does that position indicate the part  `\N{prabhu}`?

Comment: It's definitely `\N{prabhu}`. That's not a unicode character name. What symbol are you trying to get? If you replace that with some valid unicode character name it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The culprits are `\N{prabhu}` and `\U12345678`.

`\U12345678` is illegal because it is far behind the valid range limit (`0010ffff`). `12345678` in hex is `305419896` where unicode ends at `1114111` (`0010ffff`).

`\N{prabhu}` is illegal because it is not a valid unicode char name.

Comment: I thought so `:)` Example of a correct Unicode name?

Comment: I know `;)` (the valid list depends on the particular build of Python). I meant that you could include a correct example in your answer, to make it more complete.